# How to access the alert slider button in oneplus 3 programmatically?

Tags: android, android-hardware, oneplusthree

I would like to have my own android program running in the background and respond to the alert slider of op3. But i dont know how to listen to the state of the alert slider or change in the state of the alert slider.

How should i access it in the code?

Comment: I am also trying to listen for and detect the audio slider States in order to make my app respect the current ring mode, have you found a solution to this?